# There is a way to make my program send a SMS to a cellphone?

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench

So, I want to implement a function om my C# program, basically what I want to do is find a way to make the program identify the computer which its being accessed so if a not authorize computer try to access it the program will not open.

The way that I want to implement this is at the login screen the person that want to login will need to put their cellphone number and their password but if for some reason a person discover a functionary password and cellphone number and try to access the program with a computer that is not authorized to use the program the program will send a SMS to the functionary cellphone which they put and the person will need to put the aleatory code that will appear in the functionary cellphone, so basically I want to know how and if there is a way to do it, I am a noob with coding,but I appreciate any help.
(sorry for any grammar errors or bad English)

Comment: sign up for a twilio account

Comment: This is little more than an idea. [Do some research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), contact your ISP, [try some code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Your code didn't do what you thought? Post it here.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is out of scope of SO rules. I personally, would hire someone with experience to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, C# does not have a built in way to send SMS.  But fear not, there is an online API you can use that is used by a good deal of big businesses.  It's called [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms), and they have a C# library you can access.  The only issue that one might have with it is that it does cost money to use their services.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be an SMS? If not, you can use the [Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm](https://jacob.jkrall.net/totp) to have one-time codes. There are [several .NET libraries available](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22totp%22) that provide this functionality.

Comment: It actually dont need to be a sms but the problem is that i dont know how to implement this and how to join the functionary cellphone in it, i want the code to apear in the cellphone of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the cell provider, you can have your c# application send an email to a phone # and the recipient will see that message in their text conversations.  I've done this with AT&T sending an email to **phonenumber@mms.att.net**.  Of course you will have to deal with different providers and how/if they accommodate this feature.